# OData - How to define format of parameter in ODataModelBuilder ActionConfiguration

Tags: c#, .net, odata, asp.net-core-3.1

Using Odata4 in .net core 3.1, I have created an action to Bulk insert some entities, and added an additional parameter to the action:

```cs
public void Apply(ODataModelBuilder builder, ApiVersion apiVersion)
{
    var ac = builder.EntityType<MyThing>().Collection.Action("BulkAddMyThing");
    ac.Parameter(typeof(datetime), "RefDate").Required();
    ac.CollectionParameter<MyThing>("MyThings");
```

which results in a request structure in swagger that looks like this:

```json
{
  "RefDate": "2022-05-24T16:05:34.050Z",
  "MyThings": [
    {
      "Name": "string",
      "Rank": "string",
      "Level": "string",
    }
  ]
}
```

What I'd like to do is be able to force the RefDate to be a date, without the time/timezone, but I can't figure out how to define any kind of validation or default values on the RefDate parameter so that the swagger doc shows "2022-05-24" for example. I considered a string instead of a datetime with a regex as an alternative, but I'd still have trouble specifying the example input in the swagger doc.

Answer (score 0):

You should use different type, instead of `DateTime`: `Microsoft.OData.Edm.Date`
in your case:

```
ac.Parameter(typeof(Microsoft.OData.Edm.Date), "RefDate").Required();
```